# NodeJs - Net Module - Respond to data Packet wth Binary Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs application where in I need to respond to the data stream in binary format.

```
var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var PORT = 6000;

var server = net.createServer(function(dataFromPORT){
    console.log('Device Connected to Server');
    dataFromPORT.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Data Received is '+ data);
    });

    dataFromPORT.write('1','binary');
});

server.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log('Listening to Port ' + PORT);

});
```

The above code responds the packet but sends it as string 1. I need to get the responds as 0X01 ie, binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a raw byte value using

```
dataFromPORT.write(Buffer.of(1))
```

While the static method `of()` is not documented in [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), it is documented that `Buffer` implements [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), which *does* define the static [`TypedArray.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/of) method.